# Auto layout issue with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to design a custom tableviewcell with 5 UILabel in series with different width but same height for iPads in landscape,Everything works fine in previous iPads,But in 12.9" iPad i am unable to set constraint properly,I tried Aspect-Ration constraints,Priority based constraints and Constant width constraints but nothing seems to be working for me,Every-time randomly one label is getting oversizing,Do anyone known better way to solve this thing,

Comment: I fixed the issue by using multiple constraints,For fixing the width I used equal width containt with low priority and lesser than with high priority,This fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using multiple constraints,For fixing the width I used equal width containt with low priority and lesser than with high priority,This fixed the issue –

Answer (score 1):

what kinds of constraints have you set for each label?

- trailing space
- leading space
- vertical space between labels
- equals height (for each label)

in this way it should works fine.

Regarding your tableView, you are using the delegate's method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```